# Issues mapping IIS server to custom domain name in Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machine, dns, domain, iis, azure

I created a new VM from Microsoft Azure portal. I've configure my local website on IIS and its working fine when I browse my website from localhost.

Here I attached screen shot:

[image]

[image]

But I want to run my website with my domain asyncsol.com. I have successfully configured custom DNS on azure here is the screen shot:

[image]

Also I set provided azure nameservers against my domain name here is the WHOSIS screenshot:

[image]

and Configure my IIS binding settings with the same domain and its IP

[image]

after configure when I browse my domain its shows me this default page.

[image]

Now my question is how I access my website through my custom domain name. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Also I post my question on MSDN.

[MSDN Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc37a825-ffff-472d-926f-9d8e3f0c3b5f/issues-mapping-iis-server-to-custom-domain-name-in-azure-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)

I m following this tutorial for my dns configurating on Azure

[Tutorial: Host your domain in Azure DNS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns)

[image]

Comment: OK so youve set up the domain to point to the DNS servers, but have you set the DNS servers to point to your IIS server IP?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft How I can set DNS servers to point to my IIS server IP?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure DNS'es but you'll need to get access to that - I suggest contacting Azure support.

Comment: Do you have Azure web app service?

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have Azure Web App service using **nslookup** utility.

```
C:\windows\system32>nslookup www.asyncsol.com
Server:  xxxx.com
Address:  172.17.10.10

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    x.x.x.cloudapp.net
Address:  x.x.x.x
Aliases:  www.asyncsol.com
          asyncsol.azurewebsites.net
          waws-prod-dm1-031.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net
```

Probably, you need to [map your existing custom DNS domain name to Azure Web Apps.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

Navigate to your Web app service `asyncsol.azurewebsites.net`, select **Custom domains**. In the Custom domains page of the app, add the DNS name `www.asyncsol.com` to the list. Select **Validate**. The Add hostname page is shown. Select Add hostname. It might take some time for the new hostname to be reflected in the app's Custom domains page.

Comment: I see your issue has been resolved but can you tell if my reply is helpful? Or others can get a help in this case if you edit your solution here.